# Node.js/Firebase: Notifications won't reach device

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

A few months ago i started using Firebase's backend tools. they're awesome. So i had to move our current method of notifying users of their to-do list. We moved to Cloud Functions and it was 40x faster. Until a week ago i got a fresh copy of MacOS i had to delete everything in my Solid State Drive. When i did i also installed the firebase command line tools. I had my code which i used to notify users, it suddenly stopped working

Here's what happens:

When someone adds a new record to our daily list. the app notifies other family members about the new record. So i had to come up with a method to do so..

OLD CODE (worked seamlessly)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

var registrationToken = 'egV-C3ItwJE:APA91bGf5ezSRQQFHkzCNzfqhS6tiKRbs6IXXs57DFTrNCWRrVY0pZ4PHsK8G3ZjvvvO4JCvd13j_jBcJkgRh06YJ5Jw6tohc81Ro0k4HdHG-Jlv4sbW5t1DNmJBDeGf48l05eDlfMGO';


var payload = {
    data: {
        title: 'TEST/2',
        body: 'TEST/2'
      }
};

// registration token.
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response, payload);
       return
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
```

Back in my previous version of macOS this code had no issues. upgrading Firebase Command Line tools i had to make some edits to the code:

NEW CODE (NOT WORKING)

```
    // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationToken = 'egV-C3ItwJE:APA91bGf5ezSRQQFHkzCNzfqhS6tiKRbs6IXXs57DFTrNCWRrVY0pZ4PHsK8G3ZjvvvO4JCvd13j_jBcJkgRh06YJ5Jw6tohc81Ro0k4HdHG-Jlv4sbW5t1DNmJBDeGf48l05eDlfMGO';

// See documentation on defining a message payload.
var message = {
  data: {
    title: '850',
    body: '2:45'
  },
  token: registrationToken
};

// Don't use the legacy sendToDevice
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    return 

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

The Problem is:

1- When this function hits. i get the "Successfully sent message:" response. but the message won't reach the device

Things i have tried:

1- The device token is correct and i have tested it using the manual push notification on single devices

2- The device receives notifications.

3- The device runs on iOS 11.1 same as before

Thanks

Comment: Hi did u send a sample notification from firebase notification console to check that fcm token is valid one.

Comment: @sivakumar, Yes. actually i did that a couple times

Comment: Why you're not using `admin.initializeApp` in new code

Comment: @KimberlyLife can you try with my answer

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, i got 2K lines of code, it's at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u check with this function,I had tried with this I am able to get notifications.

In you first code sample u had user sendToDevice but in second sample you had used send

```
function sendPushNotification(fcmtoken, notificationTitle, notificationMessage) {
if (fcmtoken != null && fcmtoken != "" && fcmtoken != " ") {
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: notificationTitle,
            body: notificationMessage,
           sound: "default"
        }



    };

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmtoken, payload)
        .then(function (response) {

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
}
}
```

Comment: GOD you're a legend. been stuck on this for weeks. thank you